# How to connect to Cloud SQL w/ Flexible Env using Python 3.5 on Windows after app deployment?

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-flexible

I deployed an app successfully following [**this**](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment) link.

After deployment, I am having trouble connecting to Cloud SQL. In my IPython notebook, before I deploy my app, I can use the following statement to connect to my cloud instance using Google SDK:

```
cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="project_name:us-east1:instance_name"=tcp:3306
```

After entering the above, I get a notification in Google Cloud Shell

```
"listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for project_name:us-east1:instance_name 
ready for new connections"
```

I then use my IPython notebook to test the connection:

```
host = '127.0.0.1' (also changed to my my ip address for google cloud sql)
user = 'cloud_sql_user'
password = 'cloud_sql_password'

conn1 = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                         user=user,
                         password=password,
                         db='mydb')
cur1 = conn1.cursor()
```

Local test results: Can connect to Cloud SQL from IPython and query cloud database. Next step: deploy

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Result: App Deployed. However, upon navigating to my website and typing in names into the input field, it takes me to a new URL and I get the error:

```
OperationalError at /search/

(20033), "Can't connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1 (timed out))
```

My main questions are:

- How can we get PyMySQL query into a cloud database after deployment?
- Do I need a Gunicorn if I'm using Windows and need to connect to their cloud database?
- Is SQL alchemy needed for me?  I'm not using an ORM. The online instructions aren't really that clear. My local host computer is on Windows 7, Python 3 and Django.

**Edit:** I edited the file based on the suggestion by the user below.  I still get the error 'connection timed out'

Comment: Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  Change the socket in your pymysql to a unix_socket = "your cloud connection string name".  Let host be 'localhost', user = 'your cloud username' and password = 'your cloud sql password'

edit: don't forget the /cloud/ part in the connection string name

Answer (score 0):

This post is already a bit old, I hope you already solved this!

You check if you're in production like this :
`if os.getenv('GAE_INSTANCE'):`

In the documentation, they manage it this way :
`if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):`

I think that because this condition is wrong, you are overwriting the `DATABASES['default']['HOST']` value to `'127.0.0.1'`

Hope this will be the answer you were looking for!

Comment: Bit of friendly advice: your answers look really okay and all for a new user, but your username has been reported as offensive. I suggest you change it, and wish you best of luck on SO.

Comment: Is this one better ? The previous one was my real nickname 'cause it's how english people pronounce my family name ^^ Nothing else!

Comment: erm, not quite. Please pick another one (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Puss-puss)

Comment: Hey no i didn't solve this.  sorry just saw your message.  Sorry can you be a bt more clear.  What am i supposed to change?

Comment: Hey i tried your changes, and I get connection refused on localhost.  Any help?  am i supposed to change anything in my internal call to pymysql?  like pymysql.connect(host_name?)

Comment: Question, is sqlalchemy uri needed?  Im just using pymysql